# Typescript assign method to callback in TinyMce configuration

Tags: angular, typescript, tinymce

In `Typescript` I have object initialized in property, this is configuration for `TinyMce` in `Angular`

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
     tinyEditorConfig: {
       height: 900;
       // other properties here, omitted in this moment
       file_picker_callback: this.filePickerCallback
    }
    
   filePickerCallback(callback, value, meta) {
    /* Provide file and text for the link dialog */
    if (meta.filetype === 'file') {
      callback('https://www.google.com/logos/google.jpg', { text: 'My text' });
    }

    /* Provide image and alt text for the image dialog */
    if (meta.filetype === 'image') {
      callback('https://www.google.com/logos/google.jpg', { alt: 'My alt text' });
    }

    /* Provide alternative source and posted for the media dialog */
    if (meta.filetype === 'media') {
      callback('movie.mp4', { source2: 'alt.ogg', poster: 'https://www.google.com/logos/google.jpg' });
    }

    return;
  };
    }
```

How to assign this method to property. Now it shows error: `this is available only for non static member`

Sample configuration is here, but I need to move into `Typescript` and `Angular`:
`https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/full-featured/#fullfeaturednon-premiumplugins`

Comment: Can you try creating new call for config and instantiate it in your conponent ?

Comment: Could you provide minimal reproducible example on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play ? If you want to initialize `tinyEditorConfig` you should use `=` instead of `:` (`tinyEditorConfig = { ...`)

Comment: @AlekseyL. it works, thanks, I changed : to =